# dropbox - get an {"error": "Invalid origin"} when i try to upload a file

Tags: dropbox-api

I was try to upload a file using the Drop box Saver as following:

"https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/saver"

I see the Drop box saver button and when I'm clicking on it I get an error: {"error": "Invalid origin"} in a popup...

I also added to the  "Drop-ins domains the local host ip,127.0.0.1

In the popup window that open when clicking on the button there is the uri:

https://www.dropbox.com/saver?origin=file%3A%2F%2F&app_key=undefined&version=2

Maybe the problem is that after the word "file" there are the following characters %3A%2F%2F and there is no file name or location...

app_key is undefine although i added it

What can i do?

Comment: Add localhost too to the Drop-ins domains.

Comment: i did it, it is not working....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're opening your HTML directly from the file system instead of running a web server. I believe you'll need to actually run a web server (could be as simple as `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`) so the URL in the address bar starts with `http` (or `https`) and has a domain.